# Red5 Server won't start

Tags: windows-7, red5

Windows 7
Red5 1.0 RC1
Local environment

During the install I leave it blank for both the server name and the port.

I install it, and then see that Red5 appears in the Services list.

I go into properties, set it to manual, then hit start.

The service status changes to "Started", for a short while, then switches to "stopped".

No error messages or anything. It just turns itself off.

Comment: I didn't understand what you have mentioned about installing the server. I had just downloaded the zip file from their website from this link http://red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0/ and after downloading just double click a file named Red5.bat and it started. But after I restarted my system it doesn't respond at all. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @MKSingh You should create a new question and ask this. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to remove following 3 jars from your lib directory

com.springsource.slf4j.juli-1.6.1.jar
com.springsource.slf4j.log4j-1.6.1.jar
com.springsource.slf4j.org.apache.commons.logging-1.6.1.jar